# Use of undefined constant php

Tags: php

Делаю самую простую валидацию e-mail:

```
public static function checkEmail($email)
{
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Вызываю ее в коде:

```
$email = Scripts::clean($_POST['email']);
$email_validate = User::checkEmail($email);
if (!email_validate) {
    $response['errors'][] = 'Введите корректный e-mail';            
}
```

Получаю: 
`Use of undefined constant email_validate - assumed 'email_validate'`

Из-за чего это может быть?

Comment: `var_dump($email_validate)` что выдаст?

Comment: `if(!email_validate)` на `if(!$email_validate)` исправьте

Comment: еще можно `return false !== filter_var(...)`, хотя судя по тому что булевый результат тут в принципе не принципиален, то просто `return filter_var()`

Comment: @teran спасибо большое, в IDE php настройки съехали